# How do I access a JSON object that begins with NULL using gson?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to access a web API by using gson to parse through it into a string. The URL returns :

```
NULL { "status": "yes", "problem": "400072500002031600000009007000150400000396010090000003003015002065000000000703000", "result": "489672531752831649316549827238157496547396218691284753873415962165928374924763185", "time": "0.0472550392151" }
```

The above json element starts with NULL, is what is causing a problem for me to access its objects. I want to get the numbers in "result" object as a string. **Using Gson only to parse the JSON objects please.**
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This (with NULL) is not a valid JSON. Use any online validator to prove, if you need it.

If it happens constantly try to contact API provider or just remove this null in the beginning, before parsing.

EDIT:

If you can process original answer before passing to Gson deserializer you can probably do:

```
String originalJson = "NULL { \"status\": \"yes\", \"problem\": "
+ "\"400072500002031600000009007000150400000396010090000003003015002065000000000703000\", "
+ "\"result\": \"489672531752831649316549827238157496547396218691284753873415962165928374924763185\", "
 + "\"time\": \"0.0472550392151\" }";
        
String json = originalJson.startsWith("NULL ") ? originalJson.replaceFirst("NULL ", "") : originalJson;
```

Comment: Can you help me figure out how to remove the NULL part and parse it to get the "result" from the JSON? I have been trying to do that and have not been able to. Thank you!